# Matplotlib & Seaborn: Legend too long for line style

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I make plot with different kind of styles in `'-', '--', '-.'`

```
x=arange(1,9)
gmm_rsquare = [0.90,0.962,0.954,0.908,0.975,0.941,0.905,0.916,]
al_rsquare=[0.85,0.742,0.819,0.884,0.901,0.868,0.793,0.727]
emp_rsquare = [0.908,0.948,0.937,0.920,0.967,0.948,0.945,]
plot(x, gmm_rsquare, label='GMM')
plot(x, al_rsquare, '--', label='AL')
plot(x[:-1], emp_rsquare, '-.', label='Emp')
plt.axis([1,8,0.7,1])
plt.legend()
```

[image]

The legend for `-.` is not very good, because there is an addtional dash after `-.`.

The problem is also true for seaborn, and even worse

[image]

The `--` becomes `--.`, and `-.` becomes `-..`, due to the improper length of the legend.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) has an argument

> `handlelength` : float or None
> The length of the legend handles. Measured in font-size units. Default is None which will take the value from the legend.handlelength rcParam.

Hence you can set

```
plt.legend(handlelength=1.44)
```

[image]

Chosing a different fontsize may require you to chose a different `handlelength` as well.

Comment: Yes, I solve it this way. However, I want to know if there is anything that can solve it automatically?